# Loop substrings separated by comma in an entry

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's consider an entry `DOMAIN={domain1,domain2,domain3}`, how can I test if `domain1` or `domain2` or `domain3` are in the List?

For example: `list={domain5, domain 2, domain6}`

```
------------------------------------
| CONTEXT  |        DOMAIN         |
-----------------------------------|
| context1 |domain1,domain2,domain3|
|----------------------------------|
```

I tried 
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain, ',', 1) IN {'domain5', 'domain 2', 'domain6'}` but this works only for the first value before the comma (domain1)

Comment: MSSQL? MySQL? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server use user-defined function from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str)

Comment: Is there any equivalent to `dbo.fn_ParseText2Table` in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

with mysql you can concat your field and use a `regexp` like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table1
WHERE CONCAT(',', domain, ',') REGEXP ',domain1,|,domain2,|,domain1,'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator with percentage (%) wildcard character.

```
Select * From tablename
where DOMAIN Like '%domain1%'
or DOMAIN Like '%domain2%'
or DOMAIN Like '%domain3%'
```